# does nested struct initialization depend on scope?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I can't figure this out. Why does this compile:

```
typedef struct A {
    int foo[3];
} a_t;

typedef struct B {
    char tag;
    a_t foo;
} b_t;

const a_t default_a = { { 1, 2, 3 } };

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const b_t default_b = { 'A', default_a };
    return 0;
}
```

And this does not:

```
typedef struct A {
    int foo[3];
} a_t;

typedef struct B {
    char tag;
    a_t foo;
} b_t;

const a_t default_a = { { 1, 2, 3 } };

const b_t default_b = { 'A', default_a };

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}


> gcc tp.c
tp.c:13:1 error: initializer element is not constant
tp.c:31:1 error: (near initialization for ...default_b.foo...)
```

The only change is the scope of the declaration for default_b.  Why does that make any difference?  From what I can tell, either they are both valid, or should both be wrong.  But gcc (v4.7.3) accepts the first and not the second.  This is driving me nuts.

[[edit]] Follow-up question for bonus points: given that the second program is not compliant with the C standard, how may I accomplish the same thing in a standard-compliant way?  IE: a global, constant definition of default_b that includes the value of default_a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C language specification requires that an object with static storage duration be initialized with a *constant expression*.

In your first code segment, the `default_b` has automatic storage duration while in the second one it has static storage duration due to it being defined at file scope. So the second program violates the rule:

**C11, 6.7.9 Initialization**

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

The qualifier `const` does *not* mean it's a *constant expression* rather it should be read as *read-only*. A constant expression is something that can evaluated at compile time:

**6.6 Constant expressions**

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than
>   runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may
>   be.

Comment: Well, this does make sense as far as conforming to the standard goes. I can see why allowing non constant-expression initializers can be problematic. But why does it work in the second case then? Doesn't the compiler have the exact same knowledge state in either case?

Comment: It's not whether compiler could handle in such initialization (In theory, there's no reason why a compiler can't made to accept non-constant expression initializer.) rather compiler simply following the grammar and constraints defined by C language. As for *why* it was defined as such, I don't have any answer :)

Comment: The reason is that initializers for static or thread storage duration objects are generally handled by the linker/loader -- there's a fixed block of bytes in the executable image that 'initializes' the variable  when the image is loaded.  Automatic vars are stored on the stack, which has no predefined contents (it contains whatever the previous stack frame left there), so actual store instructions to initialize the var need to be generated and run as part of the function prolog, so there's no particular need for the values involved to be required to be constant expressions.

Comment: It's probably to do with efficiency (no need to generate code for initialization -- less time taken compile & less code size). Again, I don't know the exact rationale behind following such semantics in C. It's definitely not to do with compiler's limitation to generate code for that.